# Is there a way to create a composite primary key on a NetSuite custom record?

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way to create a composite primary key on a NetSuite custom record?

I know that is possible to simulate the behavior on an user event script, but I'm looking for the best practice approach here. Maybe a way to define it using SuiteBuilder.

I also know I could trick the "externalid" field to achieve the same results, but is not the real purpose of this field. The concatenation would be a problem too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NetSuite team contacted me, it turns out it is not possible to define a composite key on SuiteBuilder.

Anyway, the result can be achieved in other ways, like merging all the values in one big string, or creating an user event script to validate the fields before save.